# IllegalStateException: Illegal pop() with non-matching JdbcValuesSourceProcessingState with spring JpaRepository<>

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, parallel-processing

Having a repository implemented with CriteriaQuery, loading an entity that is part of a parent-child structure. The *Illegal pop() with non-matching JdbcValuesSourceProcessingState* exception comes up irregularly when a webservice is called in parallel that uses this repository and lazy loads the parent of the loaded entity recursively in the bussines logic. The call stack of the exception points to the line where the parent is loaded. The REST webservice is annotated with @Transactional(readOnly = true, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW). All involved classes are annotated as some sort of a Component with default scope and use default @Transactional scope of REQUIRED.

Having the parents loaded eagerly did not solve the problem. Rewriting the repository to be a JpaRepository either. But if I do both, the problem is not reproduceable anymore.

Tech. stack: spring-boot 3.1.4, hibernate 6.4.1, java 17, docker.

I do not use Uni<> nor quarkus as in other similar questions:

[Illegal pop() with non-matching JdbcValuesSourceProcessingState](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77774102/illegal-pop-with-non-matching-jdbcvaluessourceprocessingstate)

[Hibernate 6 Error InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Illegal pop() with non-matching JdbcValuesSourceProcessingState](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75345248/hibernate-6-error-invaliddataaccessapiusageexception-illegal-pop-with-non-mat)

My understanding is that this exception is caused by using an EntityManager in non thread safe way. So I would assume that using the JpaRepository solution that is designed to be thread safe should solve the problem and I do not need to load the parents eagerly.

Can somebody please explain why this exception occurs whit a thread safe usage of the entity manager?

Thanks in advance,
Ben

Answer (score 1):

I also experienced this with Spring Boot stack, no reactive style or Qarkus or anything. Turned out that the culprit was a Spring Boot JPA repository finder method that was cached. Two identical requests at the same time would end up with the same cached data, which didn't belong to at least one of the threads, thus triggering the error. Removing the cache annotation eliminated the problem.

The double requests appeared probably because some users double-clicked a web interface button that wasn't double-click proofed. The problem can be provoked at the backend by running xargs something like this to fire 20 identical requests:

```
seq 1 20 | xargs -I $ -n1 -P20 curl <your endpoint>
```

Answer (score 1):

Faced with the same error. In my particular case I had `@TransactionalEventListener` and replacing it with `@EventListener` made the error go away.

Maybe it will help someone in the future.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I found that I used wrong `@Column(name=xxx)` annotation.

I enable `spring.jpa.show-sql` and see what was sent to database. I tried to run it, but I saw that Hibernate is calling wrong field

Comment: thanks for the reply, I checked my columns, they are ok, must be something else by me